# What is the differences between storage classes

Tags: c

Could you explain easily all differences between the four storage classes with examples and usages.

I have found some information but I could not understand well.

I only know 2 things:

1) When we use the keyword 'static' in a function the variable still remains after the function ends. but what about outside of the function is it necessary?

2) When we use extern for a variable we can use it from anywhere.
but I know when we declare (int variablename) on top lines it still can be used from anywhere.

am I right about the 2 things or the only things that I know are incorrect?

and another question:are the 4 stroge classes are special for c or are they same in any other languages

Comment: Perhaps a [good (IMO) C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) might be helpful?

Comment: A more specific URL from the site indicated by @someprogrammerdude: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration

Comment: Why do you suggest there are only 4 storage classes?

Comment: I've read an pdf about c, it says "There are 4 strage classes in a C program." But I don't know other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses storage classes to let you control a variable's scope and lifetime. "Variable scope" and "variable lifetime" are concepts that almost all languages have. "Scope" is basically "what code can see/use this variable" and "lifetime" is "when is this variable created and destroyed".

"extern" doesn't create a variable or function, it just *declares* that somewhere else in the program that variable or function exists.

Hopefully this will give you enough information to find the rest of the answers you want.